# How can i go back to the start of the loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

I apologize if my problem seems long. I will try to be as succinct as possible.

Problem: Write a program that converts an imputed weight in kg to pounds. If the user enters a negative value, the program should ask the player to reenter the number.

I have created three functions.
First function - returns player input
Second function - return the weight in pounds
Third function - returns value in pounds if weight positive or ask for another input if the value is negative.

```
 # function that asks for player input in kg
    def weight_input () :
      return float (input ("Enter valid weight: "))

    weight_kg = weight_input()

    # formula to convert kg into pounds
    def weight_conversion():
      return 2.2 * weight_kg

    weight_pds = weight_conversion ()

    def weight_info () :
      while True :
        weight_kg
        if weight_kg > 0 : # if weight > 0 we return the weight in pds
          return weight_pds
        else :
          print("Invalid weight.")
          continue  # go back to the start of the loop and ask for input
      return weight_pds

    print (weight_info () )
```

My program returns the correct value if that same value is positive. However when i input a negative float number my program prints "Invalid weight" forever. I was told whenever i write continue inside a loop i return to the start of that same loop, however i cant stop my program.

Comment: It does go back to the start of the loop. But you don't call input within the loop.

Comment: but weight_kg is a variable that returns what the first function returns, and that first function returns an input

Comment: No. Weight_kg is a global variable which you set before the loop and then never modify.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is printing "Invalid weight." forever because you are taking input only once and using it every time i.e. weight_kg is never updated once input taken.

Try code

```
# function that asks for player input in kg
def weight_input () :
  return float (input ("Enter valid weight: "))


# formula to convert kg into pounds
def weight_conversion(weight_kg):
  return 2.2 * weight_kg

def weight_info () :
  while True :
    weight_kg = weight_input()
    if weight_kg > 0 : # if weight > 0 we return the weight in pds
      return weight_conversion (weight_kg)
    else :
      print("Invalid weight.")
      continue  # go back to the start of the loop and ask for input
  return weight_pds

print (weight_info () )
```

TIP: If using functions, do not use global variables. They will persist last values, and if your code needed them to change/reset in every call, prefer using function parameters

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` statement is used to skip the rest of the code inside a loop for the current iteration only. Loop does not terminate but continues on with the next iteration.

The `break` statement terminates the loop containing it. Control of the program flows to the statement immediately after the body of the loop.
If break statement is inside a nested loop (loop inside another loop), break will terminate the innermost loop.

So in your case with `continue` you just go back to the `while` still with a wrong input.

You ask for the input once, you need to ask for it again when the input is wrong.